# am i allowed to send google api oauth tokens to my server and use it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, access-token

I am developing a chrome extension that uses the chrome.identity api.
It requests an oauth_token from google for the currently logged in google user.

I now want to perform some queries to the google api using the users access token. Am I allowed to send the token to one of my servers and perform the queries on my backend, or am I only allowed to use it within the extension?

Comment: yes you can. update your privacy policy if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific policy to say that you shouldn't do this. So you can do this but make sure that this is clear to the user. Please do look at our user data [policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy)

A few considerations. Tokens and data on your server can lead to more security and privacy issues. Do you have something to protect against those issues? Is that expected by the user?